# Double Port Forwarding with two routers on the same network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm running a hand full of servers on my network. I'm running out of port forwards on my primary internet router to forward traffic from the outside to the inside. The network has another router wired to it, and I thought I could assign it a port block to forward, taking some load off of the primary router. So I configured the primary router (192.168.1.1) to forward all traffic from ports 5000 to 5999 to the secondary router (192.168.1.2) and the secondary router only lets two ports go through. The problem is nothing is getting though! Any port from 5000 from 5999 is not getting to their proper computers (two different ports for two different computers). I don't want to defer all traffic to the secondary router using DMZ, but I figured I could forward a range of ports to it. What am I doing wrong? The second router is running DD-WRT and the primary one is running the stock Netgear OS. This should be working but I know I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated. If I didn't give an important detail just ask in the comments.

Thanks again!

Comment: Oh wow, this is a Bad Idea. There's already NAT overhead, and now you want to double it.

Comment: Which is why I'm only forwarding 999 ports instead of forwarding the whole thing. I know it's going to be slower - that's why I'm choosing the least time critical applications to be on this range. Minecraft stays on the primary router whereas a simple XMPP server can be forwarded twice.